# How to auto detect and parse a date format in Julia?

Tags: date, datetime, julia

I am trying to build an algorithm to perform auto detection of date time formats and parse them accordingly. And I would like to seek some advice on improving and enhancing my algorithm.

In the following code, I tried a simple approach to build all the possible date formats and then iterate over them to match the string to dateformat, once matched it will parse the date.

#### Code:

```
using Dates
function createDateFormats()
    sep = [",",".","-","/",":"]
    dateFormatComb = []
    for i in sep
        vals = [string("dd",i,"mm",i,"yyy"),string("mm",i,"dd",i,"yyy"),
                string("yyy",i,"mm",i,"dd"),string("yyy",i,"dd",i,"mm"),
                string("mm",i,"yyy",i,"dd"),string("dd",i,"yyy",i,"mm")
                ]
        push!(dateFormatComb, vals)
    end
    return vcat(dateFormatComb...)
end

function parse(x)
    dateFormat = createDateFormats()
    try
        for i in 1:size(dateFormat,1)
             try
                 val = Date.(x, dateFormat[i])
                 yearCol = Dates.year.(val)
                 monthCol = Dates.month(val)
                 dayCol = Dates.day.(val) 
                 dayofweekCol = Dates.dayofweek.(dayCol)
                 return yearCol, monthCol, dayCol, dayofweekCol
             catch
                    continue
             end
         end
     catch 
         throw(ArgumentError("Invalid date object"))
     end
end
```

However, this is quite limited and not efficient. Also, once the time is involved the complexity increases furthermore. May I ask, if someone has a better approach to perform such operations?
Thanks, would appreciate all the suggestions and advice.

Comment: Previously, on slack someone suggested their method, but unfortunately I lost the code and due to slack limitation (free tier) I cannot access their answer. For that person, thanks brother (if you ever come across  this post).

Comment: It might be a good idea to use string manipulation ([Regular Expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#man-regex-literals)) to normalize the date time formats before trying to parse them. Also for performance reasons: Error catching is quite slow and should be avoided.

Comment: This can be surprisingly hard because the formats can vary to the point of ambiguity, especially with 2-digit years. Does it need to parse "Five minutes past noon on the second Tuesday of October next year"? You probably need to settle on a unique substring in your data that will narrowly identify a date-time and then parse that region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it that also outlines the ambiguity:

```
using Dates

const text = "2022-3-5 is one and 2021/12.14 5:30:00 is another"
const datetimeregex = 
   Regex(raw"(\d+)[:.\-/,](\d+)[:.\-,](\d+)(?:\s?T?\s?(\d+):(\d+):(\d+))?")

dt = [DateTime([parse(Int, s) for s in m.captures if s isa AbstractString]...)
                            for m in eachmatch(datetimeregex, text)]

@show dt # [DateTime("2022-03-05T00:00:00"), DateTime("2021-12-14T05:30:00")]
```

Now, what happens if the year is 2 digits? What happens if the order is mm, dd, yy versus dd, mm, yy? How do you tell whether 10-11-2021 is October 11 or November 10? In those cases you have to know what convention was used or errors will occur.

Comment: Any one can explain the complex Regex meaning?

Comment: (\d+) capture one or more digits.  [:.\-\,] one of any in ':.-,'  (?:) group but do not capture  \s?T\s? maybe a whitespace, a T, then maybe another whitespace  : a colon  And, finally,  ? at end: the grouped time data is optional.